# Chrome ssl bar wont show green

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The Secure tag displays on FF but for Chrome it wont. i pinpointed the code it doesn't like.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hx9ynL4/) (html box is the code that stops chrome showing secure}

```
<div class="santa" id="xmas" >
<p>Secret Santa Gift</p>
<a class="close_icon" id="clo" onclick="topdiv();">M</a>
</div>
```

I'm guessing it doesn't like the click action?

Edit: It was a cache issue, cleared browser history and it shows https secure. Thank you.

Comment: Your fiddle is green here in Chrome. What does the developer toolbar say? I can't see anything that'd cause issues, but maybe you're having issues with the cert on https://www.candnpropertyrefurbishment.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/xmas-compressor.png ?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your file and it seemed okay. You need to set every address on your file to https. If you had address with http change it to https.

[image]